# RS 485 occasional drop outs

Tags: rs485

I have been reading a lot on RS485 on this forum and I realised there are a lot of knowledgeable people on here, so I am going to try my luck.

I have got a panel installed this panel emits RS-485 to communicate with other slave devices. This a 2 wire system A B and a ground. The RS-485 emitting from the panel is grounded at the mains earth at the panel, and nowhere else.

There are 3 enclosures with slave devices, 2 of the enclosures are situated about 100 meters away.

- First enclosure close to the main panel - slave device powered by
  24Vac.
- Second enclosure 100meters from the main panel - slave devices
  powered by 24Vac.
- Third enclousre 100 meters away from the second -
  slave devices powered by 12Vdc.

2 slave devices on the 3rd enclosure and 1 device on the second enclosure keep on loosing comms without any reason, everything else works perfectly fine. The loss of comms occurs for less than a minute. I have changed the slave devices to new devices and still the network picks up on these 3 devices every
time.

I have checked that the slave devices are not connected to ground in their own enclosures and the earth is only coming from the panel's earth.

A 120ohm resistors is placed at the last enclosure on the last slave device. I am not sure what else to try and what to troubleshoot.

[image]

The panel does not lose any comms, only these particular slave panels, 1 in the second enclosure and 2/3 in the third enclosure. Always the same panels. Checked cabling and polarity, also changed the panels to new panels, and again these 3 are picked by the network to have comms issues.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  What speed is the communication?  When you say the devices lose communication, what do you see (a few lost bytes perhaps?  Or something else?)

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, 9600 is the speed kept it down because of the lengths, the panel measures communications, its this communications that `i see dropping. the slave panels have rx tx leds, that when the network is healthy they light in one way, however when this drop in communications occur, the leds behave in a way as the panel is interrogating the network.

Comment: "The RS-485 [] is grounded at the mains earth at the panel, and nowhere else."  So the cable shields are all tied together, and only bonded to Earth at the origin?  I bet there is significant noise on the shield at 200m, but it would be challenging to measure it accurately.  Is this physically near power wiring?  Try placing a 0.1µF 400V polypropylene cap from shield to Earth at the end of the cable; that may squelch any coupled AC noise.  Also check DC voltage from shield to Earth at both stations - should be very low (millivolts.)

Comment: Is the master transmitting all the time ... slaves say "lost comms" if they don't hear from the master within a timeout period?  Do you know what higher level protocol is used (modbus perhaps?)

Comment: Yes he master is polling all the time. Slaves drop in comms (measured in percentage) on the panel. I am trying to learn more here to see what I can measure voltage and capacitance-wise to see if it is anything like this. Yes def Modbus is used.  The time period is 700ms.. for each poll.

Comment: I can't quite grasp what you say, but RS-485 transceivers need to share a common ground reference. It could be earth or whatever but they need to share a ground. Do devices connect with two data wires AND a ground wire, or, do devices use earth as ground reference, or are devices floating in respect to each other? Or is just the shield grounded? Can you draw a diagram?

Comment: "devices  keep on losing comms without any reason, everything else works perfectly fin" ... how often do they lose it?  Do the two enclosures lose comms at the same time?

Comment: Devices loose comms with no pattern , a lot of times a day , for a few seconds and then recover.

Comment: Have you got 120R resistors at both ends of the line?  From the description it sounds like you might only have a resistor at one end.